# How to add a new OperationContract to an existing ServiceContract

Tags: c#, web-services

Sorry for the newbie question here.

I have a class marked with the [ServiceContract] attribute and I want to add another [OperationContract] to it.

That is fine but after I have done it I need the Reference.cs to reflect the change, and it doesnt.

What am i missing please?

Comment: Did you right click on the `Service Reference` in the client project and selected `Update Service Reference`? Obviously before doing that make sure that you have recompiled your service.

Comment: Have you tried after restarting Visual Studio

Comment: @HatSoft, Why would he need to restart Visual Studio?

Comment: I have noticed a lot of time VS does not reflect changes and when you restart it things go back to normal

Comment: Restarting VS seemed to do the trick - I have a lot of readonly files in the project, perhaps that was the cause.  Thanks, guys.

Comment: @HughJones are you happy to mark it as answer if i post it

Comment: @HatSoft - Yes, except I wonder if there is any further assistance you can provide.  I am getting very frustrated; I just wasted an hour trying to debug the change I just made but the new code-blocks were not getting called.  I published out of desperation, and the code change works perfectly!  Would very much appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please restart your Visual Studio, some times VS does not reflect changes and require a restart